# Windows 8 Reader Switch Between Documents

Tags: windows, windows-8, productivity

Before Windows 8, opening multiple PDFs would result in a window for each one, and you could then alt+tab between open documents.

In Windows 8, they all open to the Reader app, but only one instance is ever open. Is there a way to quickly switch between open documents using Reader?

Comment: The best way would be to just change the program set to open PDF files.

Answer (score 1):

When you have 2 or more files open in Reader you can press and HOLD right click on a file you are not currently viewing and it will let you open it in a new window.

Voilà, you now have two instances of Reader each with different files. Just do the Windows 8 split screen thingy and the can be side by side for your viewing pleasure.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Since this is not a forum, there's no need to worry about reviving old questions - provided your contribution can be useful to future visitors. Also, please do not swear.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

Have a nice day.